# 2-D Interpolation with a non uniform grid in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, interpolation

What is a good way to do 2-D interpolation from a non-uniform grid in Matlab?

My problem is similar to the one under "Grid Approximation Techniques" in the  [interpolation documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html#bs4d_b_-1), but I'm wondering if there is a better solution than trying to make the grid effectively uniform, i.e. are there any standard functions/techniques that will allow me to interpolate my non-uniformly sampled data directly, without having to interpolate my sample points, so that I can then interpolate my data.

Although values of the rows/columns in my `X,Y` arrays that describe the x,y coordinates
of the sample points of the function are monotonically increasing, they are non-uniformly spaced in the sense that `X(i,j+1)-X(i,j) ~= X(i', j+1)-X(i',j)`. 
When I provide these arrays as the first two arguments to to `interp2`, Matlab complains that:

```
Error using interp2/makegriddedinterp (line 217)
Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID.
```

If it  matters, my evaluation points `XI, YI` do form a proper meshgrid (the point is to interpolate my non-uniformly sampled data onto a uniform grid).

Comment: Have a look at the [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html) class, especially the 2D-example.

Comment: And look at `griddata`